# using external jar dependency in docker

Tags: java, maven, docker, jar

I am using external jars added through scope = system with ${basedir}/src/main/java/... added as a systempath under the dependency sub group in pom.xml.
Whenever I use the project locally from IntelliJ, there are no warnings or error. However when i try to start the .jar file from a docker container i get exceptions about the dependency.

I have tried adding the jars though Libraries under project structure in IntelliJ and just adding the jars in libs folder under the root. 
First i was providing the absolute path but then i changed it to ${basedir} because the absolute path wasn't mapped as a volume on the docker container.
Is there any way i can pack the external jars with the project jar so i could use it in a docker container?

Comment: Provide the exception details.

Comment: In the main project i call a constuctor for a class from the external jar and i cannot resolve the  import.

Comment: You need to show us how you create your docker image about that part.

Comment: its simple image using official flink docker image and i just copy the jars into it as so.. FROM flink:1.9 COPY ./jars ./jars

Answer (score 0):

IIUC you have at least two options:

#### 1. Add the JARs to a new image (per @LexByte suggestion above).

Assuming the JARs are in `${PWD}/jars` on your host machine and you wish them in `${WORKDIR}/jars` in the container:

```
FROM [[original-image]]
WORKDIR ...
COPY ./jars ./jars
```

Then, ensure your code references the JARs via the `[[WORKDIR]]/jars/[[some-jar]]`

**NB** `[[WORKDIR]]` is whatever you set as the container's working directory.

#### 2. Mount the JARs into the container using the existing image:

```sh
docker run ... --volume=${PWD}/jars:[[WORKDIR]]/jars ...
```

**NB** `[[WORKDIR]]` is whatever you will use as the container's working directory. This is the location where the JARs will be mounted in the container.

Comment: I managed to fix the problem by installing the jars locally in the maven m2 folder. Added the jars as external libraries and referenced them in the dependencies with scope run time. Building the main project jar included those libraries in the big jar. Afterwards i didnt need to add the jars in the docker image.

Comment: Between these choices - what is preferable way and why? Looks like everyone using 1 option, but it's bloating image registry