# Adding jar dependency to Spring Boot project container

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker

I have successfully created an image and it is running well, but when I try to execute an operation that is dependent on external jar, program gives ClassNotFound error. My

```
FROM openjdk:11
EXPOSE 8080
ADD target/spring-boot-docker.jar spring-boot-docker.jar
ENTRYPOINT ["java","-jar","/spring-boot-docker.jar"]
ENV CLASSPATH .;C:\Users\admin\git\repository\ImageExtractor\src\gson-2.8.2.jar
ENV CLASSPATH .;C:\Users\admin\git\repository\ImageExtractor\src\jsoup-1.14.3.jar
```

Gson and jsoup are my external jars and when run on container, they are not found. I have read related topics but could not figure it out. Any help is appreciated/

Comment: Does this answers your question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58138142/using-external-jar-dependency-in-docker